# Typescript pnpm monorepo, path aliases conflicts between local dependencies during build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, monorepo, pnpm

I have a PNPM with TurbeRepo monorepo, [used this template](https://github.com/leoroese/turborepo-tutorial). In this monorepo I have a NextJS app that uses a `ui-shared` package (local shared code, not actually an npm package).

The `ui-shared` is [made in the likes of](https://github.com/leoroese/turborepo-tutorial/tree/main/packages/ui) but my package is of course much bigger. With a `index.ts` that exports all of the components and shared utils.

UPDATE: [Added a minimal repo that reproduces the problem](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/monorepo-issue)

When building the `ui-shared` it successfully builds, but when I build the Nextjs app the `ui-shared` build fails as it fails to resolve the path from `tsconfig`. So after a couple of days of detective work I managed to single out what I believe to be the issue. When the next app builds, it builds also the `ui-shared` and that fails because the path now is based on nextjs and not the library itself. I am not sure this is the cause but I believe it is, and I don't know how can I fix that

(Shared package or package is how I'll refer to `ui-shared`)

Buiding the shared package results in success

```
ESM ⚡️ Build success in 112ms
ESM dist/index.mjs 220.69 KB
DTS Build start
DTS ⚡️ Build success in 4792ms
```

Parts of package.json

```
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "types": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint *.ts*",
    "build": "tsup ./src/index.ts --format esm,cjs --dts --external react",
    "dev": "tsup ./src/index.ts --format esm,cjs --watch --dts --external react"
  },
```

The tsconfig of the package

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/react-library.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"]
}
```

---

When I run the build of the NextJs app I get this error

```
pnpm build

> @company/business-frontend@1.0.0 build /work/company/monorepo/apps/business
> next build

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
info  - Skipping linting
info  - Checking validity of types .Failed to compile.

../../packages/ui-shared/src/components/AnimatedLoadingMedia.tsx:9:23
Type error: Cannot find module '@/utils/clsxm' or its corresponding type declarations.

   7 | } from "react";
   8 | 
>  9 | import { clsxm } from "@/utils/clsxm";
     |                       ^
  10 | 
  11 | type AnimatedLoadingMediaProps = {
  12 |   isVideo: boolean;

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/work/company/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.4_twoewwu6sg7cdf3ao6njtbftne/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:11661)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/work/company/monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/next@12.2.4_twoewwu6sg7cdf3ao6njtbftne/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12599)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
```

Nextjs app `tsconfig`

```
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/nextjs.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@": ["src"],
      "@public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@public": ["public"]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Somehow the library has to resolve its own paths when being built from nextjs. Or even better the library should be built in its own scope and the nextjs should only consume the outputs. I have no idea if it can work like that

I tried adding third party libraries but like `tsc-alias` `tsconfig-path` and so on. But the build keeps failing. I tried to see and somehow stop nextjs from building the package but I couldn't find a way

Comment: I resolved the issue by transpiling the shared code using `next-transpile-modules` and using typescript typealiases to resolve the package name to the relative location on disk. This allows for both type checking and inference while developing but also during compilation

Comment: Hi!
Could you share your solution?

Comment: @AndreyM You can use this package on all of your monorepos libraries that your app depends on https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules, after that each app/ package has to have a unique name @yourcompany/serviceA, after that you register those names into tsconfigs paths, so you cannot have `@/*`: `./src/*` for everything but instead each service has to be prefixed with `@company/serviceA/*: './src/*'`. To get path aliases to work for the packages for the nextjs app, you need to have relative paths `@company/shared-package: '../../packages/shared-package'